# How can I extract a file name based on number string?

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a list of filenames in a struct array, example:

```
4x1 struct array with fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```

where files.name

```
ans =

ts.01094000.crest.csv


ans =

ts.01100600.crest.csv
```

etc.

I have another list of numbers (say, 1094000). And I want to find the corresponding file name from the struct.

Please note, that 1094000 doesn't have preceding 0. Often there might be other numbers. So I want to search for '1094000' and find that name.

I know I can do it using Regex. But I have never used that before. And finding it difficult to write for numbers instead of text using strfind. Any suggestion or another method is welcome.

What I have tried:

```
regexp(files.name,'ts.(\d*)1094000.crest.csv','match');
```

Comment: I don't have MATLAB installation around so can't give you exact code but `strfind` runs on cell array of strings, you should try to get the file names from the structure array to a cell array and then you can find the index which contains the file you are looking for. If you decide to use `regex` regex101.com is an awesome place to test and learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the regular expression you'd want is more like

```
filenames = {'ts.01100600.crest.csv','ts.01094000.crest.csv'};
matches = regexp(filenames, ['ts\.0*' num2str(1094000) '\.crest\.csv']);
matches = ~cellfun('isempty', matches);
filenames(matches)
```

For a solution with strfind...

Pre-16b:

```
match = ~cellfun('isempty', strfind({files.name}, num2str(1094000)),'UniformOutput',true)
files(match)
```

16b+:

```
match = contains({files.name}, string(1094000))
files(match)
```

However, the strfind way might have issues if the number you are looking for exists in unexpected places such as looking for 10 in ["01000" "00101"].

If your filenames match the pattern ts.NUMBER.crest.csv, then in 16b+ you could do:

```
str = {files.name};
str = extractBetween(str,4,'.');
str = strip(str,'left','0');
matches = str == string(1094000);
files(matches)
```

Comment: Did you mean filenames(matches)?

Comment: Yes I did. Fixed.

Comment: When I use in 16A, match = contains({files.name}, string(1094000)) gives me this error: Undefined function 'string' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: String is new in 16b. In 16a you'd have to use maybe regexp instead of extractBetween, strtrim instead of strip, strcmp instead of ==, and num2str instead of string(num). I think the first regexp solution might be easiest for pre-16b.